# Calling .play() creates "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources." error

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to follow Wes Bos's Javascript30 tutorials, but when I tried making the "Javascript Drum Kit" site, I couldn't get any sound to play. The appropriate sound files are there, but when I press the keys to try to play the sound, this error message appears when I inspect the console:

`jsdrumkit.html:66 - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.`

This is the Javascript of the site:

```
function playSound(e){
    //querySelector() is just when you need a single return value
    //audio[input] is an attribute selector, and it works just like its CSS counterpart.
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if(!audio) return; 
    audio.currentTime = 0; //rewind the file to the start

    audio.play(); //**line 66 in the site's code**
    console.log(key);
    key.classList.toggle('playing');
}

function removeTransition(e) {
    if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; //skip if it's not a transform
    this.classList.remove('playing');
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

What am I missing if I can't even get .play() to work?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Perhaps your browser is missing support? You should also check the supported formats of your browser, e.g. on here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 0):

Try playing it in Firefox. An update to Chrome last year caused a problem with playing audio when it involves promises, partial content, etc. I'm working on a solution but currently haven't found one, here's info: [Audio from Icecast server not playing in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695689/audio-from-icecast-server-not-playing-in-chrome/45763666#45763666)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `<video>` tag in android cordova app. After many hours, i found, that the problem was caused by CSP (Content Security Policy), but no error message about CSP were shown in devtools (only the "no supported sources" error).

Adding this to your html file should solve the issue (But modify to fit your needs (especially, if loading some external content, restrict as much as possible to prevent XSS!)):
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * cdvfile: data: mediastream: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' cdvfile: ; frame-src * data: blob: ; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';frame-ancestors * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; media-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' cdvfile: ">`

The most important part is:  `media-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'` to allow media files (including audio) to be loaded from `blob:` data url

EDIT: Also, it was needed to workaround chrome's bug by using:

```
v.setAttribute('autoplay', 'true'); 
v.addEventListener('play', function(){this.pause()})
```

(Yes, really stupid code, but solved the issue in my case (at least in Chrome-based Android WebView))